# CSS class management with jQuery slideToggle calls

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a piece of code here that is repeated multiple times in a single html file.

```
<div class="message">
   <label id="slideDown"> Read </label>
   <p id="messageBody" class="hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
<div class="message">
   <label id="slideDown"> Read </label>
   <p id="messageBody" class="hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
```

jQuery used to slide down messageBody.

```
$('#slideDown').click(function() {
  $('#messageBody').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

My questions is how can I get it so that when I click on the label Read for one message, it only slides down the messageBody that is within its div?

Comment: `id` means **unique** identifier. You *must* use a unique string for an `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the ids `slideDown` and `messageBody` multiple times, while ids have to be unique. What happens when you use ids more than once doesn't have to make any sense at all, as your document is just malformed.

Anyway, the way to fix this would be change the ids to be unique. One way would be like this:

```
<div class="message">
   <label id="slideDown1"> Read </label>
   <p id="messageBody1" class="hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
<div class="message">
   <label id="slideDown2"> Read </label>
   <p id="messageBody2" class="hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#slideDown1').click(function() {
  $('#messageBody1').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('#slideDown2').click(function() {
  $('#messageBody2').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Alright thanks, the difficulty I have with this is the number of message divs will vary. I'm able to create unique ids for each of them, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the javascript to have click events for each one.

Comment: @Takkun The answer is to use classes instead of IDs. Check out my answer and accompanying code/fiddle.

Comment: While magzalez's answer is indeed an easier way to handle this, the problem you seem to run into shouldn't be much of a problem at all. The key would be to generate the script from the same place as you generate the html from. This can even be a good reason to use an inline script.

Comment: I was able to successfully do this by using inline scripts, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix and have less code if you change the IDs to classes like this:

HTML

```
<div class="message">
   <label class="slideDown"> Read </label>
   <p class="messageBody hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
<div class="message">
   <label class="slideDown"> Read </label>
   <p class="messageBody hidden"> Body </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.slideDown').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.messageBody').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rtZsJ/.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One additional thing if you would be willing to help. The label Read I have within a <h2> tag and I'm having trouble getting your code to execute correctly. Here's a link to the exact setup I have. http://jsfiddle.net/rtZsJ/2/

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the different HTML structure.

Comment: Per Will Klein http://jsfiddle.net/magzalez/rtZsJ/6/. He's right by the way. Might as well put your actual code in there if after we solve the problem, you're just gonna ask for the fix to your actual code.

Comment: ...and this would be the correct answer based on the original question. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML structure in your jsFiddle (see comment reply to magzalez's answer), the following should work. This requires no changes in case you add more messages later.

HTML:

```
<div class="message">
    <h2 class="messageSubject">Subject<label class="slideDown"> Read </label></h2>
    <label class="messageSender"> Sender </label>
    <div class="bodyWrapper">
        <p class="messageBody hidden"> Body </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <h2 class="messageSubject">Subject<label class="slideDown"> Read </label></h2>
    <label class="messageSender"> Sender </label>
    <div class="bodyWrapper">
        <p class="messageBody hidden"> Body </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;   
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.slideDown').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".message").find('.messageBody').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

​

Here is a jsFiddle to test (click Run): http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/7ytZR/2/